# Compare particular section of a text file with another text file

Tags: python, compare

I have a file named **fileOne.txt** as shown below

```
mystring:
   keyFile: enable
   clusterAuthMode: enable
   authorization: string
   transitionToAuth: boolean
   javascriptEnabled:  enable
   redactClientLogData: boolean

security:
   keyFile: string
   clusterAuthMode: disable
   authorization: string
   transitionToAuth: boolean
   javascriptEnabled:  enable
   redactClientLogData: boolean

test:
   keyFile: disable
   clusterAuthMode: enable
   authorization: string
   transitionToAuth: boolean
   javascriptEnabled: enable
   redactClientLogData: boolean

stack:
   keyFile: string
   clusterAuthMode: enable
   authorization: string
   transitionToAuth: boolean
   javascriptEnabled: enable
   redactClientLogData: enable
```

And another file named **FileTwo.txt** as shown below

```
security:
   keyFile: string
   clusterAuthMode: enable
   authorization: string
   transitionToAuth: boolean
   javascriptEnabled: enable
```

I need to check that, whether context of FileTwo.txt is exists in FileOne.txt or not. And print Matched or Not Matched or Not Found.

**OUTPUT -**

`Matched - security:
Matched - keyFile: string
NOT Matched - clusterAuthMode: disable
Matched - authorization: string
NOT Matched - FileString: boolean
Matched - javascriptEnabled:  enable
NOT Found - redactClientLogData: boolean`

Comment: Show some effort and post your code in your question that you tried to do and then if you stuck, specify where you are stuck and what's the problem. That's not the way to ask question!

Comment: @AkifHussain Here is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```py
import yaml  # pip install pyyaml


def read_yaml(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)


def compare(a, b):
    for key in a:
        if key not in b:
            # print('NOT Found - {}'.format(key))
            continue

        print('Matched - {}'.format(key))
        for sub_key, sub_value in a[key].items():
            if sub_key not in b[key]:
                print('NOT Found - {}: {}'.format(sub_key, sub_value))
            else:
                if sub_value == b[key][sub_key]:
                    print('Matched - {}: {}'.format(sub_key, sub_value))
                else:
                    print('NOT Matched - {}: {}'.format(sub_key, sub_value))


f1 = read_yaml('FileOne.txt')
f2 = read_yaml('FileTwo.txt')
compare(f1, f2)
```

**Output:**

```py
Matched - security
Matched - keyFile: string
NOT Matched - clusterAuthMode: disable
Matched - authorization: string
Matched - transitionToAuth: boolean
Matched - javascriptEnabled: enable
NOT Found - redactClientLogData: boolean
```

Comment: thnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

The txt files you mentioned are of `yaml` format. If you don't know about yaml then please go through https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

Parsing yaml is quite easy in python.
python comes in with `yaml` module.You can use below command to install it, if you get Import Error while importing yaml module.

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Once you are sure of yaml module installation, then please use below code

```
import yaml
with open("FileOne.txt") as fh:
    data1 = yaml.load(fh)
with open("FileTwo.txt") as fh:
    data2 = yaml.load(fh)
for key in data2.keys():
    if key not in data1.keys():
        continue
    else:
        print "Matched - %s"%(key)
        x = data1[key]
        y = data2[key]
        for k in y:
            if k in y and x[k] == y[k]:
                print "Matched - %s: %s"%(k, y[k])
            else:
                print "NOT Matched - %s: %s"%(k, y[k])
```

I hope this matches to what you need.